# Mongoose async/await find then edit and save?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, asynchronous, mongoose

Is it possible to do a find then save using async/await promise?

I have the following code:

```
try {
    var accounts = await Account.find()
    .where("username").in(["email@gmail.com"])
    .exec();
    accounts.password = 'asdf';
    accounts.save();
} catch (error) {
    handleError(res, error.message);
}
```

and I am getting the following error:

```
ERROR: accounts.save is not a function
```

Comment: `accounts` is an array of the documents found, so your code doesn't actually edit anything. What are you trying to do here?

Comment: @JohnnyHK I guess I was just playing around trying to understand mongoose, queries and promises (in the await/sync format).  I guess the above code doesn't make sense.  What if I wanted to find all the accounts with the username `hello@hello.com` and change the password to `asdf`?  I'll change the above code to reflect this question.

Comment: That still doesn't make any sense as `accounts` is still an array. Start out by using `findOne` instead of `find` and it would make more sense.

Comment: @JohnnyHK thanks!  you got me to where I needed to be.  Makes more sense now.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is what I was looking for:

```
try {
    var accounts = await Account.findOneAndUpdate(
        {"username" : "helllo@hello.com"},
        {$set: {"password" : "aaaa"}},
        {new : true}
    );
    res.status(200).json(accounts);
} catch (error) {
    handleError(res, error.message);
}
```

or (thanks @JohnnyHK for the find vs findOne tip!):

```
try {
    var accounts = await Account.findOne()
    .where("username").in(["hello@hello.com"])
    .exec();
    accounts.password = 'asdf';
    accounts.save();
    res.status(200).json(accounts);
} catch (error) {
    handleError(res, error.message);
}
```