# Why mongoose doesn't update?

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I am learning Node.js. I am stuck in this Mongoose section because of this problem.
**findById(id) doesn't get my result back and update() doesn't work**. I don't know why..

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose").set("debug", true);
mongoose
  .connect("mongodb://localhost/exercise")
  .then(() => console.log("Connected Successfully!"))
  .catch(err => console.error("Error: ", err.message));

const courseSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  tags: [String],
  date: { type: Date, default: Date.now() },
  name: String,
  author: String,
  isPublished: Boolean,
  price: Number
});

const Courses = mongoose.model("Course", courseSchema);

async function updateCourse(id) {

  const course = await Courses.findById(id);
  course.author = "Muhib";
  const result = await course.save();
  console.log(result);
}

updateCourse("5a68fde3f09ad7646ddec17e");
//  console.log(Courses);
```

I get this error :

> TypeError: Cannot set property 'author' of null

This is a snip of my record:
[image]

**btw find() works..**

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Try updating your const course to let course in updateCourse function.

Comment: thanks for answering... I get same error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the issue.. 
*there is nothing wrong with the code...*
first thing first **WHY IT DOESN'T WORK**

> This problem occurs with the imported collections only. Because the
>   imported collection contains _id property as a string

for example 
`{"_id":"5a6900fff467be65019a9001","tags":["angular","frontend"],"date":"2018-01-24T21:56:15.353Z","name":"Angular Course","author":"Mosh","isPublished":true,"price":15,"__v":0}`

**but what mongoose need is _id wrapped in ObjectId**

**SOLUTION**
when importing json object always make sure that _id is not a string but an object with a $oid as a key and _id as a value 
for example 

`{"_id":"5a6900fff467be65019a9001","tags":["angular","frontend"],"date":"2018-01-24T21:56:15.353Z","name":"Angular Course","author":"Mosh","isPublished":true,"price":15,"__v":0}`
 
should be 
`{"_id":{"$oid":"5c91a66d079f4807847fcde3"},"tags":["angular","frontend"],"date":"2018-01-24T21:56:15.353Z","name":"Angular Course","author":"Mosh","isPublished":true,"price":{"$numberInt":"15"},"__v":{"$numberInt":"0"}}`

Answer (score 0):

Try to add try/catch. I'm not sure course..save() work without err

```
async function updateCourse(id) {
    try {
        const course = await Courses.findById(id);
        course.author = "Muhib";
        const result = await course.save();
        console.log(result);
    } catch (err) {
        console.log('err' + err);
    }
}
```

Edit 1: I found a solution a this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44295672/5589964)

```
async function updateCourse(id) {
    try {
        const course = await Courses.findById(id).exec();//fixed at here
        course.author = "Muhib";
        const result = await course.save();
        console.log(result);
    } catch (err) {
        console.log('err' + err);
    }
}
```

Another solution using **findOneAndUpdate**

```
try {
    var course = await Courses.findOneAndUpdate(
        {"id" : id},
        {$set: {"author" : "Muhib"}},
        {new : true}
    );
    res.status(200).json(course);
} catch (error) {
    console.log('err' + err);
}
```

Comment: Actually it's my fault.. I forgot to mention the err above...
TypeError: Cannot set property 'author' of null

Comment: thanks again.. but the problem is not in the code as I mentioned in my SOLUTION.